# OS X Lion Server - Apache Question - index.html.en

Tags: macos, apache, osx-lion

I've added some additional sites to my apache config today, however the default document root should serve the "It Works" index.html.en apache default page. However I must of altered something by accident as it now displays the directory listing by default instead? If I navigate to index.html.en it successfully loads, but not by default when I enter 127.0.0.1 for example.
I'm sure the .en language files are resolved by httpd-languages.conf, I have doubled checked that files dependancies are included in httpd.conf 'mod_mime' & 'mod_negotiation'.

The problem shouldn't bother me to much but I would like to discover the cause if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your DirectoryIndex by putting:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html.en
```

in httpd.conf or .htaccess files.